# dd-wrt router blocks SOME https pages

Tags: dd-wrt, https

My router (dlink dir-825 with dd-wrt firmware) for some mysterious reason blocks SOME (not all) https pages. One page to be exact. I don't know why. And It's definately router problem - the page is opened just fine if I plug internet directly to my computer. The error I get is "This web page is not available (Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): The server could not be found.)". I guess it is related to DNS?

I'm completly lost.

Forgot to mention: with stock firmware the page is opened OK.

Comment: I've seen this happen randomly in Chrome and something similar in Safari back with the dir-825 and stock firmware. I recall causing and fixing the problem by changing settings that won't come to mind because it was long ago. Try google's advice (http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117805) and their discussion (http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1b6ea4f035dadc16&hl=en)

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem: I can't get a specific https page to load from any of the computers on my network that has a DIR-615 gateway with DD-WRT installed. I tried disabling QoS and resetting the router to default settings, but neither helped.